# Azure Failed to restart virtual machine - NIC is not in Succeeded state

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, network-interface

After I've broken the default user I created for VM, I wanted to reset password or create new user. I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to restart the virtual machine 'vm'. Error: Cannot proceed with
>   operation because resource
>   xx-Pipeline-Agent/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/xx-agent-ip'>xx-agent-ip
>   used by resource
>   /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx-Pipeline-Agent/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/xxx-agent442
>   is not in Succeeded state. Resource is in Failed state and the last
>   operation that updated/is updating the resource is
>   PutPublicIpAddressOperation.

I'm also trying to redeploy or restart the vm but Im getting the same error. Also I've tried this with no luck:

```
az network nic update --resource-group xx-Pipeline-Agent --name xx-agent442
```

How can I fix the state of NIC?

Comment: try and remove publicip from it?

Comment: @4c74356b41 it didn't work, was giving the exact same error.

Comment: I gave up and created another VM. 2 days later I tried to delete broken VM, NIC, Ip, it all worked that time. I also read that some people experienced this, couple of days later it is fixed magically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to go to [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/), navigate to the path, subscriptions--->resourceGroups--->providers--->Microsoft.Network--->publicIPAddresses, find the failed public IP, click `edit` and do a `PUT` operation.

If it fails, you can check the error on the bottom, if its a success, you can check in the Azure portal whether the public IP address is in the succeeded state.

[image]

You could get more details about Azure Resource Explorer: [a new tool to discover the Azure API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-resource-explorer-a-new-tool-to-discover-the-azure-api/)

Comment: I can't try that since the issue is fixed but I couldn't find doing the PUT operation on Public Ip at that time. I think this can fix the problem so I'm accepting it.

Comment: Yeah, [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/713406c2-1b6b-462a-96f3-1dd832d25893/nic-in-failed-state?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) is a similar fixed issue.